# SQL - Pivot multiple column on one pivoted

Tags: sql, pivot

I need to pivot data for below query, current data is in 3 columns Month, Case1 , case2 check image1  [current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnbSS.jpg)
I need Month to go as column and case1, case2 data under each month. check image 2 [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gGVD.jpg)

```
select 

month(pe.contact_date) as Month, 
sum (case when pt.sex_c=1 and pe.ENC_TYPE_C = '3'  then 1 else 0  end) as case1,
sum (case when pt.sex_c=1 and pe.ENC_TYPE_C = '101'  then 1 else 0  end) as case2

from
patient pt, pat_enc pe
where
pt.PAT_ID=pe.PAT_ID

group by month (pe.CONTACT_DATE)
order by month (pe.CONTACT_DATE)
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do appears to be a "transpose" operation. Here's a generic way that might be useful since I don't know if you have `pivot/unpivot' operations available.

```
select
    case when month(pe.CONTACT_DATE) % 2 =  1 then 'case1' else 'case2' end) as "??"
    min(case when month(pe.CONTACT_DATE) =  1 then case1 else case2 end) as "1"
    min(case when month(pe.CONTACT_DATE) =  2 then case1 else case2 end) as "2"
    ...
    min(case when month(pe.CONTACT_DATE) = 12 then case1 else case2 end) as "12"
from <table> pe
group by month(pe.CONTACT_DATE) % 2
```

Answer (score 0):

this should pivot the data the way you need it

```
select      case when pt.sex_c=1 and pe.ENC_TYPE_C = '3'  then 'case1' 
                 when pt.sex_c=1 and pe.ENC_TYPE_C = '101' then 'case2' 
            end as casetype,
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 1 then 1 end) as [1],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 2 then 1 end) as [2],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 3 then 1 end) as [3],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 4 then 1 end) as [4],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 5 then 1 end) as [5],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 6 then 1 end) as [6],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 7 then 1 end) as [7],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 8 then 1 end) as [8],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 9 then 1 end) as [9],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 10 then 1 end) as [10],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 11 then 1 end) as [11],
            count(case when month(pe.contact_date) = 12 then 1 end) as [12]
from        patient pt
join        pat_enc pe on pt.pat_id = pe.pat_id
group by    case when pt.sex_c=1 and pe.ENC_TYPE_C = '3'  then 'case1' when pt.sex_c=1 and pe.ENC_TYPE_C = '101' then 'case2' end
```